# Why is my query only showing one variable in my sqlalchemy flask app rather than all?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Does anyone know why this query only shows stadium_name from Stadium and not all of Fixture as well?

```
@app.route('/fixtures/', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def fixtures():
    fixtures = db.session.query(Fixture,Stadium.stadium_name).join(Stadium)\
            .filter(Fixture.stadium_id==Stadium.id).order_by(desc(Fixture.fixture_dt))
    return render_template('fixtures.html', fixtures = fixtures) #refer to template
```

Comment: Did you check `print fixtures.column_descriptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you may be overcomplicating your query. SQLAlchemy will use the relationships in your data model, as long as you have set them up correctly. I'm guessing that you have a one-to-many model of Stadium to Fixture, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
fixtures = Fixture.query.join(Stadium).order_by(desc(Fixture.fixture_dt))
```

Then, in your HTML file, you can access the fields using a dotted notation:

```
{% for f in fixtures %}
<td>{{ f.name }}</td><td>{{ f.stadium.stadium_name }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Here I've assumed that you have set up relationships similar to the [one-to-many](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#one-to-many-relationships) example. The 'stadium' is the backref from the Fixture to the Stadium.